# Stop apps from moving from secondary monitor to primary monitor when computer wakes app

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I am using Windows 8.1 with two DVI monitors and everything worked fine. I replaced the primary monitor with a higher resolution one plus displayport. Now every time the computer wakes up, all the opened apps move from the secondary monitor to the primary monitor. This is odd.

Is there a setting to control this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens, is because DisplayPort is controlled through the driver.

This means that when your OS goes into hibernation/etc, the connection to the monitor is lost. When the computer comes out of this, the connection is restored. Given that your other monitor is not having this issue, all applications are moved to the only active monitor.

There are 2 ways you can overcome this problem

1. Make sure all your monitors are driver powered (not sub-d (blue connector) but DVI, hdmi or Display Port.
2. Make sure that the 2nd monitor is connected through sub-d and your primary monitor is connected through display port. (this will definitely work)

Comment: I am not sure what changes you are telling to do. One monitor is using displayport and one is using DVI. I don't know what 'driver' means in this context. Software or hardware thing?

Comment: Plus the two monitors come online at the same time. There's no inactive monitor. I see the apps moving infront of me