# Secondary monitor waking up before primary

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep

I have two different monitors connected to my GPU, both via DisplayPort.

Whenever I wake up my computer from sleep, my secondary monitor wakes up right away, and takes control as my primary monitor, as it's the only one awake. A second or two later, my other (main) monitor will wake up and the two will swap control back and forth before settling on my main monitor being primary.

If I'm just loading in to the lock screen, this slows me down entering my password for a few seconds, and if I wake it up before the computer locks, it will shift all applications from my secondary monitor to my main monitor (similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/941553/1133957)).

I've tried swapping the order of the DP connections on the GPU, but the problem persists.

Is there a reasonable way to solve this issue, or is it simply due to the hardware of my secondary monitor waking up and securing a connection faster (thus not really fixable)?

Side note: This same issue does (of course) happen on a cold boot as well, not just from sleep.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need DP on the main? Usually HDMI will connect faster and also has Gsync, etc.

Comment: @NatsuKage DP (at least as far as I'm aware) both has better bandwidth and does have GSync/FreeSync capability.

Comment: I'm not saying it has better bandwidth. It simply syncs faster? Just try HDMI and if your monitor loads faster, then you know it's the issue. Also, if you have HDMI 2.0b, there's absolutely no reason to use DP over HDMI, unless you have an older monitor. HDMI 2.0 and DP have virtually the same characteristics.

Comment: @NatsuKage I actually swapped my secondary monitor to HDMI (rather than my main) and for whatever reason that seems to have fixed the problem after a few sleep tests.

Comment: Haha, Guess you fixed it.The more DisplayPorts connected, the more time some PCs will take time to sync since DP needs to check and synchronize both monitors. With only one DP and one HDMI, they don't need to fight each other.  Also, I was wrong...Gsync still isn't supported over HDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my solution here in case other people have the same issue.

Because I wanted to keep the best connection on my main monitor (DisplayPort), I swapped my DP connection on my secondary monitor to an HDMI connection and I no longer had any issues on startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate where the problem is, and you have the available material to test, I'd recommend trying the same steps on a different PC with the same monitors.

If you have the exact same behavior on a different PC, then you know the problem is coming from the monitor themselves, if not, then you try using a different GPU, different cable, etc... until you pinpoint the culprit